# Check URL file existe from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to do the following things:

```
1 - open a text file containing a list with URLs (http://example.com). <br>
2 - read the text file and check if the path existe. <br>
3 - write the results back in another text file.
```

I have tried the following code:

```py
    import urllib2
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')

    search = urllib2.urlopen(file + "/js/tools.js")

    if search.code == 200:
        print "Exists!"
```

I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Can you please include the text file, or at least enough of it to demonstrate what your input looks like?  Then, also provide what the output that you want looks like.

Comment: Your are directly passing a `file` object to `urlopen`. Shouldn't you rather loop over it and pass each line? Also, is `/js/tools.js` supposed to be suffixed to every url in the input file?

Comment: This line doesn't look right: `search = urllib2.urlopen(file + "/js/tools.js")`.  `file` is a file handle, not a string.  You need to use that handle to read the contents of your file.

Comment: @Steve the file contains of lists of domain name ex. domina1.com domain2.com etc.. // and if the path /js/tools.js exist on the domain1.com i want it be writen on another text file.

Comment: @TheGamer007 yes i want to loop it and check if exist on every line.

Comment: @prashantrana's answer sounds like it's close to what you want then.  Just add the `/js/tools.js` on to each url read from the file.  You might need to add `http://` to the front of the line as well.

Comment: @steve not working.

Answer (score 0):

considering you have file `Filename` as links are stores line by line

```
import requests
with open(filename,'r') as file, open(filename2,'w+') as file2:
    for url in file.readlines():
        check = requests.get(url)
        if check.ok:
            file2.write(url)
```